# I am not able to filter date to Month, Year, Date with generated excel using epplus

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, excel, epplus

I have a view, from which I filter data and show the search results, I changed the Date format to

```
convert(varchar(11),getdate(),113)
```

This is the format in view

After downloading in excel, it is just giving all dates. No grouping is available.
I tried several formatting to change the date format in Excel as well as code like

```
ews.Column(i).Style.Numberformat.Format = "d-mmm-yy";
```

but no use.

My View returns date like `19 Mar 2014`

I want grouping of date with format as `19-Mar-2014`

Please suggest me a working answer.

Comment: Are you sure, the "dates" you got with `convert(varchar(11),getdate(),113)`are really dates in Excel, not just text? For data transfer I would use ever ISO date format yyyy-mm-dd. So use `convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 120)` to get really dates in Excel and then format them in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do any conversion in the view, e.g. just have it return getdate() and set the format in EPPlus code.  I use this for one of my projects and it will allow selection / format correctly in Excel going this route.

Comment: I just got date and then formatted, so it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jordan in that you should not format the date within the database, but return it to your .NET code as a SQL DATETIME, C# DateTime. If you do that, you have more control over how you can write it into the spreadsheet.

```
var file = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\ExcelDemo.xlsx");
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");

    var date = DateTime.Now;
    worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = @"Date Raw";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = @"Date Raw with Style.Numberformat.Format = ""D-MMM-YY""";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = @".ToString()";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = @".ToString(dd MMM yy)";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = @".ToString(yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz)";

    worksheet.Column(2).Style.Numberformat.Format = "D-MMM-YY";

    worksheet.Cells[2, 1].Value = date;
    worksheet.Cells[2, 2].Value = date;
    worksheet.Cells[2, 3].Value = date.ToString();
    worksheet.Cells[2, 4].Value = date.ToString(@"dd MMM yy");
    worksheet.Cells[2, 5].Value = date.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz");

    package.Save();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select replace(convert(varchar(11),getdate(),113),' ','-')
```

Comment: I tried the same, but no use, It shows the date in that format, but grouping is done.

Comment: Please avoid code-answers solutions, and explain what is going on